# Counting duplicate records within duplicate records using SQL select statement

Tags: sql

I have a table with duplicate tag_id, and  serial numbers.  How could I display a list of  distinct tag_id and the number of serial numbers related to it.   In other words, I need to know how many serial numbers each distinct tag_id has.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query..

```
 SELECT YourColumn, COUNT(*) TotalCount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY YourColumn
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: I think that will only find the duplicates in a column.  I need to display unique tags_id in one column, and then the number of  serial numbers assigned to it in another column.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Dyrandz had, but counting the number of serial numbers per tag id as you requested.

```
DECLARE @YourTable AS TABLE (
    tag_id     INT,
    serial_no  VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @YourTable (tag_id, serial_no)
VALUES (1, 'abc'), (2, 'cde'), (3, 'def'), (1, 'xyz'), (3, 'lmn')


SELECT tag_id, COUNT(serial_no) AS TotalSerialNumbers
FROM @YourTable
GROUP BY tag_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: I think that will work, but I'm getting an SQL0440N error (No authorized routine named "COUNT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found).  I need to use CAST to convert the serial number field. I tried --Select tag_id, count (cast serial_number as integer) -- but didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Got it to work.  I just replace COUNT(serial_no) with COUNT (1).  It ignores the name of the column and returns the output needed.  Thanks to both of you, Mr Moose and Dyrandz.